# Got an error message when using summarise inside for loop

Tags: r, dplyr

Having a list containing 244 data frames. This list is called d, and `d[[1]]` looks like this.

```
d[[1]]

   year  pos  days   sal
1  2009  A     31   2000
2  2009  B     60   4000
3  2009  C     10    600
4  2010  B     10   1000
5  2010  D     90   7000
```

I would like to group data by year, adding days and sal, and select pos where days is maximum in the group.

The result is like:

```
 year   pos  days   sal
1 2009    B    101   6600
2 2010    D    100   8000
```

I know how to do this when it comes to the case doing it to only one data frame.
I did it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
ygroup<-group_by(d[[1]]$year)
summarise(ygroup, pos = pos[which.max(days)], days = sum(days), sal = sum(sal))
```

But I want to do this same operation to the 244 data frames in the list d.
I tried this:

```
e<-list()
ygroup<-list()
for(i in 1:244){
ygroup[[i]]<-group_by(d[[i]]$year)
e[[i]]<-summarise(ygroup[[i]], pos = pos[which.max(days)], days = sum(days), sal = sum(sal))
}
```

But this doesn't work, an error showing up.

```
Error: expecting a single value
```

(I think this part;   `pos = pos[which.max(days)]`   is making the problem, but I'm not that sure...)
How can I solve this...?

Any comments will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Try with `lapply` i.e. `lapply(d, functiion(x) x %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(pos = pos[which.max(days)], days = sum(days), sal = sum(sal)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `lapply` with anonymous function call to loop over the `list` of `data.frame`s ('d')

```
lapply(d, function(x) x %>% 
                       group_by(year) %>% 
                       summarise(pos = pos[which.max(days)], 
                                 days = sum(days), sal = sum(sal)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in e[[i]]<- you might be better off using lapply rather than looping

```
ygroup<-lapply(ygroup,FUN=group_by,d$year)
e<-lapply(ygroup,FUN=summarise,pos = max(days), days = sum(days), sal = sum(sal))
```

Which will return a list so no need for e<-list()